# PushingViewController in AppDelegate unrecognized selector to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've been searching arround stackoverflow and I am not able to fix my problem, I have the following code in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboard bundle: nil];
        InternetConnectionViewController *controller = (InternetConnectionViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: noInternet];
        [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But is giving me an error...:

```
Uncaught exception: -[CustomSplitViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17884860
2016-06-16 02:34:14.896 --[3340:1197655] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomSplitViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17884860'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x20c6b91b 0x20406e17 0x20c712b5 0x20c6eee1 0x20b9a238 0x23005d 0xb1cb7f 0xb1cb6b 0xb21655 0x20c2db6d 0x20c2c067 0x20b7b229 0x20b7b015 0x2216bac9 0x2524d189 0x18abdb 0x20823873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

**EDIT - UPDATE**
I manage to achieve it and now is working... but when I try to do this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    HomeViewController *controller = (HomeViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: viewC];
    [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

in the InternetViewController it gives me the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setPanGestureEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16942a00'
```

Comment: Is it possible that rootViewController is `CustomSplitViewController`, which is not of type `UINavigationController `?

Comment: As seen in the error this is possible, I do have two different times when the InternetConnectionViewController appears, if the user is logged it will be in the CustomSplitViewControllr if not it will be in the LoginViewController

Comment: I run some tests and this is only happening when I am in CustomSplitViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create property in AppDelegate.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
```

Then

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

MainTabBarController *mainTabbarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabbar"];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainTabbarController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: This seems to be working, I am doing some test in different controllers and accept your answer later.

Comment: I have a new problem I am trying to do this:
    `UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
HomeViewController *controller = (HomeViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: kHome];
        [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`

but I have the same error: 

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setPanGestureEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16942a00' `

Comment: Why you are making this confusing... Here you are pushing VC but you have to just change the rootVC of the navVC. And when you wish to get previous VC then use same code and change the expected vc.

Comment: If you are changing VC from any controller (Not from AppDelegate.m) then you can access storyboard instance globally. Do not use appDelegate's storyboard (which is created manually.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboard bundle: nil];
InternetConnectionViewController *controller = (InternetConnectionViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: noInternet];
UINavigationController *navObj = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
self.window.rootViewController = navObj;
```

Hope this Helps!